# Can't attach Visual Studio for Mac debugger to Unity 2020

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-mac

The option "Attach to Unity" does not appear on Visual Studio for Mac:

[image]

Also, on Unity's Preferences -> External Tools, I don't see a "Editor Attaching" option:

[image]

Everything was working fine a couple of days ago, and I didn't update Unity, Visual Studio, or macOS.

Any ideas?

**Environment:**

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Unity 2020.1.4f1 Personal
- Visual Studio for Mac Community v8.7.8 (build 4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone going through the same problem, I just had to go to Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools -> and click on "Regenerate project files". [This thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-see-attach-to-unity-button-in-visual-studio.463530/#post-5890835) helped me.